# Learn python the hardway ex17, outside the box

Tags: python-2.7

Belive me, i've try my best to print "to_file" after rewriting it in vain !
It appears that "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found"

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line, how?
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
print open(out_file).read()
```

Comment: What line produces this error?

Comment: The last line causes error